# Updated: When to "mortalize" a variable in Perl Inline::C

Tags: c, perl, memory-leaks, inline

I am trying to wrap a C library into Perl. I have tinkered with `XS` but being unsuccessful I thought I should start simply with `Inline::C`. My question is on Mortalization. I have been reading perlguts as best as I am able, but am still confused. Do I need to call `sv_2mortal` on an SV* that is to be returned if I am not pushing it onto the stack?

(PS I really am working on a less than functional knowledge of C which is hurting me. I have a friend who knows C helping me, but he doesn't know any Perl).

I am providing a sample below. The function `FLIGetLibVersion` simply puts `len` characters of the library version onto char* `ver`. My question is will the `version_return` form of my C code leak memory?

N.B. any other comments on this code is welcomed.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use 5.10.1;

use Inline (
  C => 'DATA',
  LIBS => '-lm -lfli',
  FORCE_BUILD => 1,
);

say version_stack();
say version_return();

__DATA__
__C__

#include <stdio.h>

#include "libfli.h"

void version_stack() {

  Inline_Stack_Vars;
  Inline_Stack_Reset;

  size_t len = 50;
  char ver[len];

  FLIGetLibVersion(ver, len);

  Inline_Stack_Push(sv_2mortal(newSVpv(ver,strlen(ver))));
  Inline_Stack_Done;

}

SV* version_return() {

  size_t len = 50;
  char ver[len];

  FLIGetLibVersion(ver, len);
  SV* ret = newSVpv(ver, strlen(ver));

  return ret;

}
```

Edit:

In an attempt to answer this myself, I tried changing the line to

```
SV* ret = sv_2mortal(newSVpv(ver, strlen(ver)));
```

and now when I run the script I get the same output that I did previously plus an extra warning. Here is the output:

```
Software Development Library for Linux 1.99
Software Development Library for Linux 1.99
Attempt to free unreferenced scalar: SV 0x2308aa8, Perl interpreter: 0x22cb010.
```

I imagine that this means that I don't need to mortalize in this case? I suspect that the error is saying that I marked for collection something that was already in line for collection. Can someone confirm for me that that is what that warning means?

Comment: I don't know Perl, much less how to integrate it with C ... but, if your code is plain old C and there are no "tricks" in `libfli.h` the lines `Inline_Stack_Vars;`, `Inline_Stack_Reset;`, and `Inline_Stack_Done;` have no function whatsoever.

Comment: @pmg, there is lots of magic that happens between Perl and C; those functions are defined in headers that automatically get read before compiling.

Comment: Did you try [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) already?

Comment: @hlynur, I did give that a quick look, but I fear it will suffer from some of the same problems as my XS attempts, namely that I don't know enough of what I am doing to succeed at using it. The library needs to use a makefile to compile to a .so, therefore using `h2xs` was confusing for me and I imagine that `swig -perl5 ...` would be as well. In the end I will probably need to write my own XS as the library has a confusing mechanism which will not map to Perl very well, at least not idiomatically. Still my question is independent of all that, I'll get to that when I get there.

Answer (score 1):

I've been maintaining Set::Object for many years and had this question, too - perhaps best to look at the source of that code to see when stuff should be mortalised (github.com/samv/Set-Object).  I know Set::Object has it right after many changes.  I think though, it's whenever you're pushing the SV onto the return stack.  Not sure how Inline changes all that.